# Silverlight run DispatchTimer only once

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to figure out a way in Silverlight / C# to make a DispatchTimer run only once.

I have a user form and when submitted I want to display a message for 10 seconds and then disappear and kill the DispatchTimer thread.

I know how to make a DispatchTimer that repeats:

```
clock.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
clock.Tick += clockTick;

clock.Start();
```

But I want that thread to end as soon as it completes.

Comment: Can you just stop the timer on the first line `clockTick` event handler?

Comment: Are you stopping any actual processing in that thread? If not why don't you simply use an animation storyboard and catch the completed event? This gives you nicer options for removing the message in an animated way as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
DispatcherTimer clock = new DispatcherTimer();
clock.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
clock.Tick += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    clock.Stop();
    // Some code here
};
clock.Start();
```

An anonymous event handler will also keep things "in the same place" in case you don't want to widen the scope of your DispatcherTimer object.

Comment: VS is telling me instead of `object e` it should be `System.EventArgs e` but I think this should work beautifully thank you.

Comment: ahh, you're right! I'll change that :) But I'm glad this helped

Answer (score 1):

Stop the timer in your clockTick handler once it fires.