# c# Wait condition to continue foreach loop

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, foreach

So in Silverlight behind code, I am doing a async call into a foreach loop, that call a method.

The thing is, I want to wait, until the method is called, and then , continue the loop.

```
        foreach (Object itm in DataSource.DataView)
        {
            DispatcherTimer clock = new DispatcherTimer();
            clock.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8);

            clock.Tick += (object sendC, EventArgs c) =>
            {
                clock.Stop();
            //new System.Threading.Timer(openCallBack, 0, 2000);
                open(0, itm);
                // Some code here
            };
            clock.Start();
        }
```

So here, I am creating a timer, that wait for 8 seconds. Like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438631/silverlight-run-dispatchtimer-only-once)

The problem is, the loop continue, even if Im' not going in the Tick event.

The result is, I'm going 3 times in my tick event, with the last, and same object. It's really unconveniant.

So, I want to wait to continue the foreach, until I go through the `Tick`.

```
            bool continue = false;
            foreach (Object itm in DataSource.DataView)
            {
                DispatcherTimer clock = new DispatcherTimer();
                clock.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8);

                clock.Tick += (object sendC, EventArgs c) =>
                {
                    clock.Stop();
                //new System.Threading.Timer(openCallBack, 0, 2000);
                    open(0, itm);
                    continue = true;
                    // Some code here
                };
                clock.Start();

             //continue loop if continue is true
            }
```

So, that the `open` method is actually call every 8 sec.

How can I do this?

Comment: What about `await Task.Delay(8000)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you're trying to do something that Silverlight was explicitly designed to NOT allow you to do (perform synchronous long-running activities).

I'd recommend that you refactor this: create a class that is passed your IEnumerable that creates a DispatchTimer and has a start method where you wire up the callback and start the timer. Then on each Tick callback, you move to the next item (terminating if there is no next item) using MoveNext and call the Open method. (I'd also recommend a Cancel method so you can terminate the processing, surfacing some kind of status event, etc.)

```
...
var myProcessor = new SerialProcessor(((IEnumerable)DataSource.DataView).GetEnumerator())
myProcessor.Start();
...

public class SerialProcessor
{
    private IEnumerator items;
    private DispatcherTimer clock;

    public SerialProcessor(IEnumerable items)
    {
        this.items = items;
        this.clock = new DispatcherTimer();
        clock.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8);

        clock.Tick += (o, e) =>
        {
            clock.Stop();
            if (!this.items.MoveNext()) return;
            var item = this.items.Current;
            open(0, item); // <-- This is where you do whatever processing you want to do. If you want to be REALLY slick, pass it into this class as a Func<> or Action<>
            // Resume processing
            clock.Start();
        };
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        clock.Start();
    }

    // Add Cancel method to stop the clock, status events, etc.
}
```

Comment: So basically, I will use a IEnumerable object, and loop through it, instead of my dataSource. And the IEnumerable object will  be construct with my foreach? I don't know well this kind of object, I'm looking somme infos right now.

Comment: Nah, instead of using a foreach (which implicity calls GetEnumerator), you'd pass the result of DataSource.DataView.GetEnumerator() to this class. I'll amend my response with some sample code.

Comment: I have this message in my page(silverlight page, client side) for GeEnumerator : Error 481 'System.Windows.Controls.DomainDataSourceView' does not contain a definition for 'GetEnumerator' and no extension method 'GetEnumerator' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DomainDataSourceView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). And about the same message on the Class SerialProcessor(class client side).

Comment: Hm. They may have explicitly implemented IEnumerable. Try this: ((IEnumerable)DataSource.DataView).GetEnumerator()

Comment: Wups! Corrected the datatype for items in the SerialProcessor to IEnumerator.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. And so `this.items = items.getEnumerator();`